# Can't write file using MySQL data

Tags: python, mysql, database, file, file-io

I get this error:

```
TyperError: sequence item 2: expected string, long found
```

Here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/HhD6cSsD):

```
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "*****", db = "test")
cursor = connection.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM names")
data = cursor.fetchall ()
no = []
no += ["<users>\n"]
for row in data :
        no += ["        <user id='", row[0], "' name='", row[1], "' blend='", row[2], "'/>\n"]
        no += ["                <nick color='0x", row[3], "' font='", row[4], "'/>\n"]
        no += ["                <glow color='0x", row[5], "' alpha='", row[6], "' blurX='", row[7], "' blurY='", row[8], "' strength='", row[9], "' quality='", row[10], "'/>\n"]
        no += ["        </user>\n", row[11]]
cursor.close ()
connection.close ()
no += ["</users>"]
s = ''.join(no)
file = open('test.xml','w')
file.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating strings into sub lists the way you're doing it, you can do something like the following

```
# Don't do this
no += ["        <user id='", row[0], "' name='", row[1], "' blend='", row[2], "'/>\n"]

# Do this instead
no += ["        <user id='%s' name='%s' blend='%s'/>\n" % (row[0], row[1], row[2])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your retrieved data to string first using `str()` so anywhere where it says `row[INDEX]` you have to say: `str(row[INDEX])`. `str(row[3])` for example.